# Each open interval is a countable union of closed sets.

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

How can we prove this $$(a, b)= \cup_{n=1}^\infty [a + 1/n, b - 1/n],$$ ?

First: it is clear that $\left [ a + \frac{1}{n}, b - \frac{1}{n}\right ] \subseteq (a, b)$ for every n, then $\cup_{n=1}^\infty [a + 1/n, b - 1/n] \subseteq (a, b) $. what about the other inclusion?

Comment: What have you tried? The statement can be (partially) rewritten as: for any $x$ such that $a<x$ there is $n$ such that $a+1/n<x$.

Comment: @freakish $a+1/n\le x$, actually.

Comment: Is this Archemedian property? @freakish

Comment: @Secretly yes, it is.

Comment: Still I am stuck @freakish

Comment: one direction is clear for me, this one $\subset$ (sorry I meant the other inclusion but I do not know how to write it in latex) @freakish what about the other direction?

Comment: @Secretly if $x$ is such that $a<x<b$ then there is $n$ and there is $m$ such that $a+1/n\leq x$ and $x\leq b-1/m$. Let $k=max(n,m)$. Then $x\in [a+1/k, b-1/k]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x\in]a,b[$. Then $a<x<b$. Let $\epsilon_1 = x-a$ and $\epsilon_2 = b-x$. Choose $n^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n^*}  < \min\{\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2\}$. Then $x\in [a+\frac{1}{n^*},b-\frac{1}{n^*}]\subset \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty [a+\frac{1}{n},b-\frac{1}{n}]$.